# Assigning values to multiple outputs syntax problem - `,` or `;`

Tags: vhdl

I want to assign multiple values to signals as shown in example below. Do I separate values there by `;` or `,`?

Example:

```
opcode : process (OP)
begin
    case OP is
        when CALL   =>  AOp <= "000", -- am I separating right?
                        ALS <= "0",
                        OE  <= "0",
                        RE  <= "0"; -- should the last one be a ;?
        ....
```

**CALL** is a constant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They should all be semicolons:

```
opcode : process (OP)
begin
    case state is
        when CALL   =>  AOp <= "000";
                        ALS <= "0";
                        OE  <= "0";
                        RE  <= "0";
        when ....
```

Each one is a complete assignment statement. Any number of statements can follow a `when` clause.